# PyQt5 : are pyqtSignals thread safe?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, signals-slots

I am learning how to use PyQt5 and there are quite a few points that elude me.

I have started implementing QThreads to replace the threads I have been using in my UI as I realised that mixing threads and QThreads could possibly lead to issues later and have started using pyqtSignal simultaneously

So far I have seen that the pyqtSygnal needs to be implemented on a class level to be able to work ( putting it in a class constructor does not work )

In the architecture I use currently, I have a pyqtSignal that is instantiated in the main thread and is then used by all of the child threads. This is due to having one class that is responsible for my logs of all the program.

I am unsure if this is a good implementation or not.

Here are my questions :

- are pyqtSignals thread safe ?
  I know that they use a queue system to be thread safe but is the `emit()` method itself thread safe ? My understanding of them is a bit limited
- Do I need to protect my pyqtSignals with locks ?
- Can I have multiple different signals emitting to the same slot without having any issues ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "one of the pyqtSignals that I use is shared by multiple QThreads"? Do you mean that you're using multiple instances of a QThread subclass that has a custom signal?

Comment: edited my question for clarity. Currently I do not have QThreads but normal threads ( have not yet finished the implementation of the QThreads ). The way I am implementing thing I would have QThreads that use the same pyqtSignal that is implemented in the main thread and then given to the QThreads to use. Did not go any further as I realised this may not be a good idea ( I did not see pyqtSignals being implemented this way ) but am struggling to understand the do / don't.

Comment: From the OOP perspective (especially encapsulation), you should emit a signal from the object that is "conceptually" signaling. So you should not emit the signal of another object, but create custom signals in the QThread subclass and emit from there. There's little to no benefit in trying to emit a signal from a different source.

Comment: Thanks, I do think it's good practice and going to be easier to debug / fix at a latter stage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signals are one of the few elements of the QObjects that are thread-safe so it is not necessary to protect the data. So you can have different types of signals connected to the same slot.

Since the signals are thread-safe then Qt recommended to communicate QObjects that live in different threads.